# How to render different Layouts using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to show Navbar only for this url: `/contact`, `/services`. And I don't want to show Navbar for `/signin`. For this moment this is what I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import PublicLayout from './components/layouts/PublicLayout';
import SigninLayout from './components/layouts/SigninLayout';

import Main from './components/pages/Main';
import Services from './components/pages/Services';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">
                  <Switch>                    
                    <PublicLayout>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
                            <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
                            <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                    </PublicLayout>
                    <SigninLayout>
                            <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
                    </SigninLayout>
                  </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When I go to `/signin` url it still gives me Navbar. So guys - how do you render different layouts for different pages in React? Please help!

**UPD:** My PublicLayout Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../nav/Navbar';

class PublicLayout extends Component {
    state = {
        items: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Услуги', link: '/services' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Как это работает?', link: '/contacts' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Войти', link: '/signin' },
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar items={ this.state.items } />
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PublicLayout;
```

My SignInLayout code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SigninLayout extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SigninLayout;
```

My SignIn component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Signin extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Войти</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="укажите e-mail" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="укажите пароль" />
                    <button>Войти</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Signin;
```

Comment: I've only ever done this rather badly; I rendered a component at the top level, and then changed it's rendering conditionally based on the route. I'll be interested to see some better solutions

Comment: Can you show us the SigninLayout, PublicLayout and Signin component code?

Comment: @c-chavez updated my question with code samples. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: For latter users, pls check this code example 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-multiple-layout-forked-y5i1e

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this by first choosing which layout to render using your switch statement, and then moving the routing for components that should be rendered inside that layout to *inside* the layout component.

As a very basic example, your `App` component could have:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/signin" component={PrivateLayout} />
      <Route path="/" component={PublicLayout} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now inside PublicLayout, you can render the Nav and also create some new routes e.g.

```
class PublicLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Public Place</h1>
        <Navbar items={[]} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
          <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
          <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PublicLayout;
```

...and in PrivateLayout you can render a set of routes without the NavBar e.g.

```
class PrivateLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Private Place</h1>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path="/signin/otherpath" component={OtherPrivateComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PrivateLayout;
```

Here it is all in one file, which you can also [see on this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q37o4z7jm9):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = props => <div>Nav Bar</div>;

class PrivateLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Private</h1>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/signin" render={() => <h2>Signin</h2>} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/signin/otherpath"
            render={() => <h2>Signin Other</h2>}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PublicLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Public Place</h1>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <h2>Main Page</h2>} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signin" component={PrivateLayout} />
          <Route path="/" component={PublicLayout} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Yep, I tested it locally. What do you see when you try that means it isn't working?

Comment: It doesn't render anything except main page with navbar and main page content.

Comment: This is how my App look like: http://prntscr.com/ky4r4w This is PublicLayout http://prntscr.com/ky4rcd

Comment: I've updated my answer with both a link to a working example, and a code example of this working with several components inside a single file.

Comment: I found an error! <Route exact......> in App class. So if <Route exact path='/signin' component={SigninLayout} /> it won't work. But IF without <Route path='/signin' component={SigninLayout} /> it will. Can you explain why?

Comment: For all those that will use this article, please make sure that you define the "/signin" route before the "/" route. The "/" route should always be the last route defined.